# jQuery find all elements with class beneath parent, even in children elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is some sample HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="searchEl"></div>
    <div class="searchEl"></div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="searchEl"></div>
        <div class="searchEl"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is a jQuery function:

```
$(function(){
    $(".parent>.searchEl").each(function(){
        $(this).html("Found this one");
    });
});
```

The DOM elements will end up like so:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="searchEl">Found this one</div>
    <div class="searchEl">Found this one</div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="searchEl"></div>
        <div class="searchEl"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using jQuery/Javascript, how can I search for and find all the elements with class `.searchEl` beneath the element `.parent`, even if they are within another child element, without searching the document globally with `$(".searchEl")`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use a space instead of `>`

```js
   $(function() {
     $(".parent .searchEl").each(function() {
       $(this).html("Found this one");
     });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="searchEl"></div>
  <div class="searchEl"></div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="searchEl"></div>
    <div class="searchEl"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

Remove `>` from your select

```
$(".parent .searchEl").
```

You can use the `.find()` method also,

```
$(".parent").find(".searchEl")
```

Answer (score 8):

`>` will select only direct descendants/children. Remove `>` to select all the descendant elements.

```
$(".parent .searchEl")
```

You can also use `find()`

```
$(".parent").find(".searchEl")
```